# PowerShell, only run Set-Execution if it is not already set?

Tags: powershell, executionpolicy

I have a script that tries to run these...

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force -ea silent
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -ea silent
```

But I get this error:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Windows PowerShell updated your execution policy successfully, but the setting is overridden by a policy defined at a
more specific scope.  Due to the override, your shell will retain its current effective execution policy of Bypass. Type "Get-ExecutionPolicy
-List" to view your execution policy settings.
```

So I tried this:

```
if ($(Get-ExecutionPolicy) -ne "RemoteSigned") {
    Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope CurrentUser RemoteSigned -Force -ea silent
    Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Force -ea silent
}
```

But I get the same error (I thought this might skip the `if` body if I tried this.

I then tried

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope MachinePolicy Unrestricted
```

but I get this error:

```
Cannot set execution policy. Execution policies at the MachinePolicy or UserPolicy scopes must be set through Group
Policy.
```

But I don't use policies or anything AD related on my home system.

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -list

        Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser    RemoteSigned
 LocalMachine    RemoteSigned
```

How can I run the `Set-Execution` if the policy is not set, and skip that if it is not set?

Comment: Please add the output of `Get-ExecutionPolicy -List` before and after the script (if it changes). Did you start powershell.exe with `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass`?

Comment: It's unchanged as I'm running the script by right-clicking on and selecting "Run with PowerShell". The reason those lines are in the script are that I use it to start Windows Sandbox, so they need to be there to enable script execution inside the Sandbox. But then I need to rerun that startup script to enable new features as I'm testing, but I always hit this error. I need a) for the execution policy to be turned on as part of startup, then b) be able to run it over and over inside the Sandbox and want to bypass that (slightly annoying) error if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scope is `LocalMachine` if you don't specify one. The message appears because `CurrentUser` takes priority over `LocalMachine`. One way to check is:

```sh
# [optional] temporarily suppress execution policy warnings
$E = $ErrorActionPreference
$ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope LocalMachine) -ne "RemoteSigned") {
  # will always error if CurrentUser scope is set already
  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine -Force
}

if ((Get-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser) -ne "RemoteSigned") {
  Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
}

$ErrorActionPreference = $E
```

The warning can't be suppressed normally since it's written directly to the console for some reason.

---

Alternatively, you can set only the `CurrentUser` scope. If you're not using group policy, then there are only three scopes to worry about. The **highest** one takes priority (setting lower ones will show the warning):

1. `Process`: Set for only the current process `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope Process`
2. `CurrentUser`: Set for only the current user: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser`
3. `LocalMachine`: Set for all users: `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

For more information, check out [about_Execution_Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies)

Comment: That worked perfectly, and thanks for the clear explanation of why this happens..